# Список установленных приложений без приватного api

Tags: objective-c

Может кто то знает вот  используя runtime можно взять список  приложений

```
    Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"defaultWorkspace");
NSObject *workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:selector];
SEL selectorALL = NSSelectorFromString(@"allApplications");
NSArray *list = [workspace performSelector:selectorALL];
[list enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *_Nonnull stop) {
    NSLog(@"item %@", [obj valueForKey:@"_bundleExecutable"]);
}];
```

Но это приватное api, и в appstore оно не попадет. Тогда не понятно как работает тот же cleaner и другие приложения. Может есть способ какой то другой или opensource project?

Comment: а что такое cleaner?

Comment: чистильщик мусора в кэша, он  в appstore есть. Даже если сранить с антивирусом(он же тоже установленные приложения находит) и эти приложения не забанены.

Comment: посмотреть его где то можно? по слову cleaner выдает мильен приложений

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/phone-cleaner/id1092614777?mt=8

Comment: так он только одинаковые фотографии удаляет. или я что то пропустил

Comment: кэш приложений, cockies, дупликаты фотографий,очищает память

Comment: где нажать чтоб увидеть список приложений, установленных на телефоне?

Comment: извеняюсь в ios appstore cleaner  нету такого. Но вопрос был если использовать private api то забанят. А что можно использовать для этого чтоб не забанили и приложение попало в аппсторе

Comment: давайте вы все таки найдите сначала хоть одно приложение в аппсторе, которое имеет такую функциональность, и тогда поговорим. а пока что предлагаю считать, что это невозможно.

Comment: Извиняюсь удалю свой пост , был не прав